# indexes in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

What are the pros and cons of using indexes in Oracle SQL?

For cons, I have:
Indexes have the following disadvantages - they increase the disk space requirements of the database, they slow down dml (inserts, updates and deletes), they increase the maintenance needs of your database, they may make your queries slower instead of faster.

What are the pros of using indexes?

Comment: They make queries run faster.

Comment: select queries actually.  As noted above insert, update, and delete queries will run slower.

Comment: @DanBracuk they *can* also speed up delete and update queries (because those usually have a `where` clause that can make use of an index)

Comment: this is not different than any other database. Really a data model and no indexes? what is the justification?